# Breaking google sheet table into smaller tables and send gmail to corresponding emails(google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way that we can break the main table below into smaller tables and email (gmail) them to the corresponding email on the first column?

| Bank's Email | Client name | Age | Bank with |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bank1@hotmail.com | Client 1 | 19 | Bank 1 |
| bank1@hotmail.com | Client 2 | 32 | Bank 1 |
| bank1@hotmail.com | Client 3 | 22 | Bank 1 |
| bank2@hotmail.com | Client 4 | 34 | Bank 2 |
| bank2@hotmail.com | Client 5 | 22 | Bank 2 |
| bank1@hotmail.com | Client 5 | 28 | Bank 3 |

For example, send the below table as gmail to bank 1's email ?

| Client name | Age | Bank with |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | 19 | Bank 1 |
| Client 2 | 32 | Bank 1 |
| Client 3 | 22 | Bank 1 |

and below to bank 2's email (same with bank 3)?

| Client name | Age | Bank with |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 4 | 34 | Bank 2 |
| Client 5 | 22 | Bank 2 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.  I leave it up to you to adjust the styling to suit your taste.  I edited this to add the first part. Sorting the clients.

```
function test() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
    // dont get header
    var data = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var banks = [];
    data.forEach( row => banks.push(row[0]) );
    banks = [...new Set(banks)];
    var results = [];
    function addClient(row) {
      var i = banks.indexOf(row[0]);
      if( results[i] === undefined ) results[i] = [];
      row.shift();
      results[i].push(row);
    }
    data.forEach( addClient );
    results.forEach( (bank,index) => createTable(banks[index],bank) );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

function createTable(email,data) {
  try {
    var table = "<table style='border-width:thin;border-style:solid;border-color:black'>";
    function addCell(value) {
      table = table.concat("<td style='border-width:thin;border-style:solid;border-color:black;width:20px'>");
      table = table.concat(value.toString());
      table = table.concat("</td>");
    }
    function addRow(row) {
      table = table.concat("<tr>");
      row.forEach( addCell );
      table = table.concat("</tr>");
    }
    data.forEach( addRow )
    table = table.concat("</table>")
    console.log(table);
    MailApp.sendEmail( {
      to: "thewized@gmail.com",
      subject: "Test",
      htmlBody: table });
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```